# Firebase Messaging with Flutter - json configuration file from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to add FCM push notifications to my Flutter app. I went to https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/ to see where to start. But they say there's no any integration required at android side. On native Android, I need to register my app in Firebase, add some entries to .gradle files and download `google-services.json` file. Flutter docs says I don't need `google-service.json` and I actually don't need to do anything.

Please clarify - without `google-service.json` how is it supposed to work? Or their manual is incomplete?

Comment: for android native you need google-service.json file to be added. As I'm an android developer we add json firebase file for connection to firebase.

Comment: I know I need it for android native. But how is it supposed to work without that file with Flutter? Or I need it on Flutter too, but their docs does not say anything about that? The didn't mention I need to register on Firebase nor download any json and put it to my project

Comment: In flutter, you have to add firebase for android and iOS or web separately.

Comment: check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android . look at the stage 3

Comment: `If you are using Flutter Android Embedding V2 (Flutter Version >= 1.12) then no additional integration steps are required for Android.` - from link I pasted. They say I don't need to do anything. They did not mention I need to register the samy way as on native andoid

Comment: Ok but I don't if I add json file just to preventing any future trouble.

Comment: You were right in FlutterFire Plugin, you dont need json file.

Comment: So, I don;t understand how it can be handled by my Firebase account. FCM support requires app registration, afaik. I'm confused.

Comment: I think FlutterFire plugin has it already. For example in android studio(android native) you can add firebase with firebase tool. In that you just click and your firebase is ready to go. Just like that flutterfire will be containing all the required information.

Comment: Ok, on native Android I need to register my app with Firebase, then get server key and auth key from Firebase to send push message to may app. When app is not registered, where can I get keys from?

Comment: First connect your app to firebase by FlutterFire Plugin.

Comment: Ok, but that step is not mentioned as required here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/ the say I need to add dependency and then I can start using it without any additional steps required

Comment: Ok I was wrong. They actually mentioned to initialize Flutter Fire first.

Comment: ok. good to know.

Comment: I should post the detail answer for you ?

Comment: I think there's no need to do so. But I must say, sometimes their documentation is confusing a bit.